# Make Firefox remember CSS changes on a domain basis

Tags: firefox, css, adblock

I am surfing to websites that keep telling me to deactivate my adblock. Ehm, no. I will not. I do understand that those website make money through advertisment and that's fine. As long as there is no exploit in JavaScript. Or this advertisment is placed on a web site that cross scripts vulnerabilites of this website. Target advertisment placement makes it possible. And the website owner doesn't even know it. So, my answer to adverbs is no.

Okay, but now to the gist. When there is a specially obnoxious piece of anti-adblock notification, I can't just click it away. I do have to F12, find the div and display none it.

That's tedious if it happens again and again. But I couldn't find any addon that allows me to make changes like that permanently. So what I am looking for is an addon that I can set up rules like this:

```
DOMAIN="*testdomain.com*"
CSS_to_add=".addblockermessage { display: none;}"
```

I did some research. I couldn't find anything similar. If anyone does know an addon that does that or an alternative way to reach the same goal, please tell me. Because otherwise, I feel forced to write my own addon. But why invent the wheel twice... Plus a lot of other inconveniences.

(PS: That addon could also be used to display a website in a completely wrong font. Especially if it's a family computer and you don't like Facebook. Make your family wonder why it's suddenly Comic Sans and the background is pink.)

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Uh.. That is so neat. Why didn't I know about this before. It is perfect. Would you please be so kind to transform your comment into an answer, so I can mark it as the solving answer?

Comment: Answer added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I am looking for an addon so that I can set up rules

```
DOMAIN="*testdomain.com*"
CSS_to_add=".addblockermessage { display: none;}"
```

[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) is perfect for this.

> **About this Add-on**
>
> Allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by
> using small bits of JavaScript.
>
> You can write your own scripts, too. Check out
> http://wiki.greasespot.net/ to get started. Many scripts already
> exist, probably ones to enhance your favorite sites. Find them at
> http://wiki.greasespot.net/User_Script_Hosting .

Source [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what an ad blocker is meant to do for you. Note that those "detection" scripts **do not** detect whether an ad blocker is installed, only whether specific requests were blocked and/or specific elements on the page hidden.

Disabling the default filter list for blocking ads - EasyList - will therefore stop the ad blocker from blocking ads and thereby also stop the detection. You can still add your own custom filters though to block/hide whatever you want.

In your example, just add the filter `testdomain.com##.adblockermessage` and the ad blocker will hide the element with the class "adblockermessage" on any webpage on the domain "testdomain.com".

Source: [adblockplus.org/filters](https://adblockplus.org/filters)